# Prevent CSS3 Columns from Reflowing on Content Change

Tags: css

I've created a template page that displays WordPress query results in two neat columns using the CSS3 `column` attribute. The results flow beautifully, except for when I dynamically change the contents of the columns using (something like) JavaScript.

In my case, each WordPress result shown is a `<ul>` element with its `<li>` children initially hidden. When the child elements are unhidden, the columns sometimes reflow to keep the same symmetry. From an aesthetic standpoint it's great, but from a functional standpoint it jumps my content around and that is not my intent.

Is there any way to easily prevent the `column` from reflowing after it has initially been established? I would prefer to continue using this technique rather than using another method to establish the columns.

I'm currently just using simple markup and CSS:

```
<div class="results-list">
  <!-- PHP/WP Query Stuff in here -->
  <ul class="fa fa-plus"> <!-- The query expand button -->
    <li class="hide-me"> A hidden query result</li>
    <li class="hide-me"> Another hidden result</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.results-list {
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

Before Image:

[image: Before Expansion]

And after an item is expanded, notice how the top line of the right column has reflowed back to the bottom of the left column:

[image: After Expansion]

I would rather it simply push down the right column. Maybe it's not possible using `column`, but I thought I'd ask!

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: @GibboK Gah! Sorry. I know better than that.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work for me; basically after columns have been laid out normally, add some extra styling to fix the tops of each column:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var last = 0;
    jQuery('.results-list ul').each(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).offset()['top'] <= last) {
            // start of new column
            jQuery(this).css({
                'column-break-before': 'always',
                'break-before': 'column'
            });
        }
        last = jQuery(this).offset()['top'];
    });
});
```

If the above works correctly, just the `Office Supplies & Printing` container should get the extra CSS, which will then prevent it being reflowed back into the first column when any of the succeeding content changes.

---

Note: If manually setting column breaks via CSS only, I'd use the following:

```
-webkit-column-break-before: always;
break-before: column;
```

But jQuery 1.8 [says it will apply the vendor prefixes](https://api.jquery.com/css/), however the `column-break-before` doesn't seem to be getting applied in Chrome, although it still works as intended for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Should be accepted answer.

Comment: Hey @EoghanM, sorry I hadn't seen this for some reason. I'm just trying it now so I can mark correct, but could you clarify where the break-before property goes? (e.g. is it on the parent with the column property, or on the individual list items inside?)

Comment: Nice idea, also have to take in account if there is only one box in a column to add a break.